# Adding new server to sharepoint 2013 farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

I have 2 tier SP farm (SP and SQL)
I want to add new server(3rd) with following PowerShell script, the same error with Configuration wizard

```
Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseServer "192.168.1.108\SharePoint" -DatabaseName "SP_Config"
```

> Error:
>       Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase : Не удалось применить изменения web.config к ф
>       айлу "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\MySite Host-8080\web.config".
>       Не удалось применить изменение веб-конфигурации к файлу "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss
>       \VirtualDirectories\MySite Host-8080\web.config".  Указанный узел "system.web/h   ttpModules" не найден в файле web.config.
>       строка:1 знак:1
>       + Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseServer "192.168.1.108\SharePoint" -D
>       ata ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

After mySite deletion same error with Main Portal:80 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Web.config file of "MySite-Host-8080" having some issue which causing the issue when you trying to add the server.Looks like you made changes in the web.config file and remove/ add some tags.

Now you have two options, if you are not using the MySite-host web app then you can simply delete it and rerun the config wizard on new server.

Or Fix the the issue `specified node "system.web / h ttpModules"` and re run the config wizard. You can compare the web.config from other web application and add that node.

Comment: thanks, Idelete mysite and contentdatabase properly from IIS. But the same error with Main Portal:80  web.config, I do not want delete my Main portal due to this issue