# Web.config error when adding new server to production SP 2013 Foundation farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, web-config, configuration-wizard

First off, I've been scouring the posts here and elsewhere looking for a solution to this issue, and I appreciate any help.  The closest I have found is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119052/adding-new-server-to-sharepoint-2013-farm/119058#119058), but the answer was not followed-through.  My apologies if this is a "obvious" question as I'm new to SP development and have recently inherited this farm from the previous admin.  I am trying to add a new application server to the farm to facilitate search indexing as it has become too much to handle for the single server that currently comprises the farm.

The error message I am getting when adding the server (either through the wizard or powershell) is:

```
Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase : Failed to apply web.config modifications to file
'E:\Inetpub\SharePoint\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config'. Failed to apply a web.config
modification to file 'E:\Inetpub\SharePoint\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config'. The
specified node "configuration/system.webServer/staticContent" was not found in the
web.config file.
```

I have checked the file, and this node is present and populated.  Also, I have verified permissions for this account on the SQL server in case that matters.  Both servers are on the June 2016 CU, and I have also made sure the passphrase is correct by changing it a few times.  This caused a need to rebuild the cache so that has been completed, also.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: which web.config is giving error? central admin or web application or?

Comment: This web.config is for the main web application.

Comment: How any servers in the farm

Comment: The Web Config is case sensitive.  Make sure you check the case of the nodes.

Comment: One WFE application server in the farm and one SQL server. Trying to add a second application server.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues with the letter casing of the file.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

- go to the IIS Manager, Click on the Server and in the feautre pane select the configuration Editor
- On this page from drop down Exapand **System.WebServer** and Click on the StaticContent
- Now on in Action Tab(right hand side) Make Sure it say **Lock Section** if not then unlock it.
- Do this on all Servers and reset IIS.

This link is basically go through the above steps

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33768.sharepoint-2016-central-admin-error-http-500-the-website-cannot-display-the-page.aspx

Comment: The section shows as unlocked with the "Lock Section" option available.

Comment: Ok then click on unlock, it should say locked and re ran the config wizard? Make sure it shows lock on all server especially on the new server

Comment: To clarify, under Actions > Section it should say "Lock Section" or "Unlock Section"? It currently shows "Lock Section"

Comment: It should say lock section

Comment: Yes, that is what is currently showing. Could this message also appear if there's an issue connecting to the configuration database?

Comment: Is it on new server and after iisreset did you ran the config wizard